# Cannot create DaskDMatrix

Tags: xgboost, dask-distributed

I am trying to train an xgboost model with dask following the documentation. My problem is that I am blocked at the step where I have to create a DaskDMatrix. No matter how I try, I receive an error that this method doesn't exists. I tried:

```
import dask
import dask_xgboost as dxgb

client = dask.distributed.Client()

params = {'objective':'binary:logistic', 
        'booster': 'dart', 
          'n_estimators': 800,
          'max_depth': 4,
          'learning_rate': 0.02, 
          'random_state': 42}
}

dtrain = dxgb.DaskDMatrix(client, X_train, y_train)
dval = dxgb.DaskDMatrix(client, X_val, y_val)

eval_set = [(dtrain, 'train'), (dval, 'validation')]

model = dxgb.train(client, params, dtrain, num_boost_round=10, evals=eval_set, eval_metric=['logloss', 'aucpr'], verbose=True)
```

==> "AttributeError: module 'dask_xgboost' has no attribute 'DaskDMatrix'"

Then I tried:

```
import xgboost as xgb

# Create a Dask DMatrix from a Dask DataFrame
dtrain = xgb.dask.DaskDMatrix(client, X_train, y_train)
```

==> AttributeError: module 'xgboost' has no attribute 'dask'

And also:

```
import dask_ml.xgboost as dxgb

# Create a Dask DMatrix from a Dask DataFrame
dtrain = dxgb.DaskDMatrix(client, X_train, y_train)
```

==> AttributeError: module 'dask_ml.xgboost' has no attribute 'DaskDMatrix'

Where I can find the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

Working code with a freshly conda installed xgboost and dask-xgboost on my laptop, and following [the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/dask.html):

```py
import xgboost as xgb
import dask.array as da
import dask.distributed

client = dask.distributed.Client()

params = {'objective':'binary:logistic', 
        'booster': 'dart', 
          'n_estimators': 800,
          'max_depth': 4,
          'learning_rate': 0.02, 
          'random_state': 42}

X_train = da.random.random((10,100000))
y_train = da.random.random((1,100000))
dtrain = xgb.dask.DaskDMatrix(client, X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meanwhile I discovered that xgb.dask requires xgb version > 0.9